как округлить число до десятых в меньшую сторону с определенным шагом python
Знаю звучит как извращение, но мне правда нужно )

задача: на пример есть число 2.75, по итогу мне нужно округлить любые числа > 2.5 в собственно 2.5 и меньшие тоже.

если по простому тогда вот пример:

a = 2.75 должно превратиться в 2.5


b = 2.23 должно превратиться в 2.5

то есть как бы к центру и нет речь не о конкретно этих числах из примера, но не нашел ни одного примера или инструмента который позволит это сделать на python

решение должно быть универсальным для всех десятичных чисел, при целом числе оно какое есть такое и остается, то есть 1, 2, 3, 4 итп не меняются


Уточню на всякий случай. А если число 3.23? Оно округляется до 3.5?

Или если число 3, куда оно должно округляться? До 3.5?

решение должно быть универсальным для всех десятичных чисел, при целом числе оно какое есть такое и остается, то есть 1, 2, 3, 4 итп не меняются

(math.floor(x) + math.ceil(x)) / 2

а вот это работает, большое спасибо <3

При x = какое-то число x if x % 1 == 0 else x % 1 + 0.5

Ну неверно же..
